# FullCalendar-Scheduler Google Calendars ResourceIDs Query

Tags: json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, gcal

*Reference: FullCalendar 3.9.0, FullCalendar-Scheduler 1.9.4*

Can anyone confirm whether or not it is possible to group Google calendar events by resource? Adding a resourceId parameter to a calendar source as follows:

```
    var myCalSrc = {
    id: 1,
    googleCalendarId: '<myCalSrcURL>',
    color: '<myCalSrcColor>',
    className: '<myCalSrc-events>'
};
```

results in a blank display. The following note in the FullCalendar-Scheduler gcal.html file located in the demos directory states:

> ```
>   /*
>   NOTE: unfortunately, Scheduler doesn't know how to associated events from
>   Google Calendar with resources, so if you specify a resource list,
>   nothing will show up :(  Working on some solutions.
>   */
> ```

However, the following threads appear to suggest there may have been a fix for this:

[GitHub - Add ResourceId Parameter to gcal.js (fix supplied)](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3020)

[GitHub - Specify resourceId in Event Source settings](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/124)

However, checking the gcal.js file reveals the fix has not been added to that file.

Is it possible to manually assign a resourceId to each of the Google Calendar feeds in order to replicate the Resources and Timeline view indicated by the [FullCalendar Timeline View documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view)?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing the code to: 
 `var myCalSrc = { id: 1, googleCalendarId: '<myCalSrcURL>', color: '<myCalSrcColor>', resourceID: 'a' className: '<myCalSrc-events>' };` and adding: 
 `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... resources: [ { id: '1', title: '<myResourceTitle>' }, ... ], ... ` fails to display any events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the issue in your second GitHub link (which your first one was merged with), https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/124, the fix you mentioned is still awaiting testing (as of 11 Mar 2018). So if you're patient it will likely be added to a future release, assuming it passes the tests. In the meantime, here is a potential workaround:

In fullCalendar it's possible to define a separate eventDataTransform for every event source.

Therefore I think you should be able to use this to set a resource ID for each event depending on the Google Calendar it came from:

```
eventSources: [
  { 
    googleCalendarId: 'abc@group.calendar.google.com', 
    color: 'blue',
    eventDataTransform: function(event) {
      event.resourceId = 1;
      return event;
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    googleCalendarId: 'def@group.calendar.google.com', 
    color: 'green', 
    eventDataTransform: function(event) {
      event.resourceId = 2;
      return event;
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    googleCalendarId: 'ghi@group.calendar.google.com', 
    color: 'red' ,
    eventDataTransform: function(event) {
      event.resourceId = 3;
      return event;
    } 
  }
]
```

I'm not able to test this right now but it looks like it should work. Hopefully this will take place before it's rendered on the calendar and needs to belong to a resource.

Comment: Hi ADyson, Thank you for the workround. That now allows the events to be displayed correctly. One thing I've noticed though is that an fc-icon class is added before the resource titles (effectively showing as an unnecessary preceeding space) when switching from agendaDay view to timelineMonth. If I set the default view to timelineMonth the an fc-icon class is not initially added and so the titles display without the unnecessary initial space before the titles.

Comment: That sounds like a separate UI question related to the timeline view. If the answer above helped you with the google calendar question, please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks. I suggest you ask a new question regarding the icon issue.

Comment: Thanks, ADyson. Will do.