# FullCalendar GCal ResourceIDs Query

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, gcal, resource-id

Reference: FullCalendar 3.9.0, FullCalendar-Scheduler 1.9.4

As the [original question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904638/fullcalendar-scheduler-google-calendars-resourceids-query) received no response I'm trying again.

Can anyone confirm whether or not it is possible to group Google calendar events by resource? Adding a resourceId parameter to a calendar source as follows:

```
var myCalSrc = {
id: 1,
googleCalendarId: '<myCalSrcURL>',
color: '<myCalSrcColor>',
className: '<myCalSrc-events>'
```

};
results in a blank display. The following note in the FullCalendar-Scheduler gcal.html file located in the demos directory states:

> /*
>     NOTE: unfortunately, Scheduler doesn't know how to associated events from
>     Google Calendar with resources, so if you specify a resource list,
>     nothing will show up :(  Working on some solutions.
>     */

However, the following threads appear to suggest there may have been a fix for this:

[GitHub - Add ResourceId Parameter to gcal.js (fix supplied)](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3020)

[GitHub - Specify resourceId in Event Source settings](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/124)

However, checking the gcal.js file reveals the fix has not been added to that file.

Is it possible to manually assign a resourceId to each of the Google Calendar feeds in order to replicate the Resources and Timeline view indicated by the FullCalendar Timeline View documentation?

Changing the code to:

`var myCalSrc = { 
id: 1, 
googleCalendarId: '<myCalSrcURL>', 
color: '<myCalSrcColor>', 
resourceID: 'a', 
className: '<myCalSrc-events>' 
};`

and adding:

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... resources: [ { id: '1', title: '<myResourceTitle>' }, ... ],`

... fails to display any events.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar-Scheduler Google Calendars ResourceIDs Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904638/fullcalendar-scheduler-google-calendars-resourceids-query)

Comment: I have answered your original question. Please don't post duplicate questions. Editing your original will push it back up the feed if you want to try and get it some attention